# unable to publish a VB.net project using msbuild

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

Ok, I am trying to publish a vb.net web application project using msbuild. I am running msbuild from a jenkins.  I build three solutions in order as the first two provide necessary references for the last solution.  The last solution contains the web application project that I am trying to publish.

So I run msbuild three times, one for each solution and then I run msbuild on the project to publish the web application project.  I run the following command to publish the project:

`msbuild.exe webApp.vbproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=local.pubxml`

the publish file resides in the sub folder that lies under the project folder at:
    `"My Project\PublishProfiles\local.pubxml"`

I got the project to publish once, but have been unable to reproduce. I had a previous post on the issue, but I have not gotten the results to work consistently for me:

[msbuild unpublishable project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453509/msbuild-unpublishable-project)

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is "local.pub.xml", why are you passing "Local.pubxml"?

Comment: That was I typo that I fixed. The publish file is called local.pubxml

Answer (score 0):

Folks:  The msbuild.exe in the initial question above is good and will work.  The issue I ran into was that the .vbproj files was modified while testing and a key section was commented out.  The command works as adverstised.